# Fix project structure for Heroku deployment MEAN

Tags: node.js, heroku, angular8, file-structure

I'm working on my first MEAN stack project and all was well until I tried to deploy it to Heroku.

The problem is, I separated back and front end on two separate folders on the root directory. Now, when trying to build the page to be served, I get a log error like this:

```
 !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
 !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
 !         
 !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
 !     the directory structure.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
 !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
 !     following files:
 !     
 !     BlackBooksbackend/
 !     BlackBooksfrontEnd/
 !     README.md
 !         
 !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
 !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
 !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
```

I'm aware that the log error is pretty straight forward but I couldn't really find clear instructions on how to solve the issue. It seems that Heroku prefers to be deployed at the frontend folder but the Angular buildpack does not run anyway. I tried setting up ith [this one](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/nitinhayaran/heroku-buildpack-angular-spa). The log error was similar to the output above.

Does anyone have any tips or tutorials on how to sort this out?

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: This [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) has Node/Express backend and React frontend in different directories. Can be easily deployed to Heroku though it gets data not from MongoDB but rather from different sample API service.

Comment: Cool. I had a look at it and it's lit. Unfortunately, that helps very little with the issue I have up there.

Comment: Unless you'd like to adopt the suggested approach: (1) Forget about Heroku and its buildpacks for a moment and build a [container](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+express+container), then run it locally using Docker thus proving your Dockerfile is working. (2) Use simple [sequence](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/README.md#using-heroku) of heroku-cli commands to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: So, I'd use a Docker container to setup the install env for Heroku. Okay, thanks a million. I will try this and let you know :) Sillyme for not thinking Docker from day 1, though.